# How to Hide Tables from view if Value = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that counts msg types from one table. At any given time, maybe a dozen will display any results depending on what transactions are going on in the db. I want to be able to display COUNTs ONLY for any MSG_TYPE_ID that has a value > 0

SAMPLE QUERY:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT  (CASE WHEN MSG_TYPE_ID = '0'   THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Type 0'
 ,COUNT  (CASE WHEN MSG_TYPE_ID = '1'   THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Type 1'
 ,COUNT  (CASE WHEN MSG_TYPE_ID = '2'   THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Type 2'
 ,COUNT  (CASE WHEN MSG_TYPE_ID = '3'   THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Type 3'
 ,COUNT  (CASE WHEN MSG_TYPE_ID = '5'   THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Type 5'
FROM DB1 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Expected output

```
Type 0 Type 1 Type 2 Type 3 Type 5
67     0      0      47     56
```

How do I hide any msg_type column from display that shows '0' ? There are about 85 msg_type_id's so this list is rather large from left - right. And if I could hide them, it could clean that view up

Comment: You do this in the presentation tier. SQL Server treats a query and its result set as a contract. You can do this with really ugly nested dynamic SQL, but it is much easier to show/hide columns at the layer where you're actually showing the data,.

Comment: A view has a fixed number of columns, it's not dynamic. You can't just hide one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  You could get what you want using dynamic SQL.  But an easier solution would be to put the values on separate rows:

```
SELECT MSG_TYPE_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM DB1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE MSG_TYPE_ID IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '5')
GROUP BY MSG_TYPE_ID;
```

This will only output the values where records exist.

Comment: Perfect. That did exactly what I wanted. Thank you Gordon

Answer (score 0):

if you want a variable number of columns, you can do with cursor but is some ugly.
you parse the rows, save in a string a query and execute the string

```
declare @id int
declare @msg_type varchar(100)
declare @query varchar(100)
set @query=''

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT MSG_TYPE_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM table WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY MSG_TYPE_ID
Having count(*) >o

OPEN mycursor

FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor 
INTO @msg_type, @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if @query <> '' 
    begin
       set @query = @query + ', '
    end

    set @query = @query + cast(@id as varchar) + ' as ' + @msg_type

FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor 
        INTO @msg_type, @id
END 
CLOSE mycursor;
DEALLOCATE mycursor;
set @query = 'select ' + @query
print @query
EXECUTE (@query)
```